# После "семьями" требуется знак? Можно ли оправдать точку с запятой после "памяти"?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире, точка-с-запятой

> Заведение до сих пор обожают сами местные, а может, посещают по старой
>   памяти; так появляется – во-первых – редкая возможность в несезон
>   наблюдать вблизи сцены из жизни самых настоящих итальянцев, которые
>   передвигаются гигантскими семьями от старушенций в креслах-каталках до
>   новорождённых. Во-вторых, на обед ресторан радует возможностью
>   разнообразного открытого буфета – 30 евро с человека (без напитков).

Какие ещё замечания к стилю и пунктуации?

Режет глаз первое-второе то в тире, то с запятой?

Ресторан радует возможностью буфета ***на обед***?

---

Мой вариант правки (после невежливо-назойливых комментов); согласны ли вы с ним? Жду дополнений и уточнений. Или отмены какой-нибудь правки, ибо автора надо щадить...

*Заведение до сих пор обожают сами местные, а может, посещают по старой памяти... Так появляется, во-первых, редкая возможность в несезон наблюдать вблизи сцены из жизни самых настоящих итальянцев, которые передвигаются гигантскими семьями: от старушенций в креслах-каталках до новорождённых. Во-вторых, в обеденное время ресторан радует возможностью разнообразного открытого буфета – 30 евро с человека (без напитков).*

Comment: Мне одному кажется, что это домашнее задание?

Comment: Нет, совершенно верно кажется - это надомная работа ("домашнее задание") редактора на пенсии. Он (я) дочищает текст перед публикацией.

Comment: Домашние задания не проверяются, думаю, по той простой причине, что откроешь калитку, — дом снесут могучим потоком.

Comment: Эт почему ж?! Мне какой-то значок посулили, если буду в том же духе стараться... Текстов полно; почему редактор не может проверить свои сомнения, тем более что обычно предлагает свой вариант правки. Ради Ваших прекрасных глаз, предъявлю свою правку до рассмотрения кляузы модераторами...

Comment: Есть и такая причина, думаю: однозначного ответа на несколько вопросов в одном тексте получить невозможно. Редактировать абзацами и главами можно, но вопросы-ответы должны быть штучными.

Comment: Поправочка! Я не прошу ссылок на правила и/или аргументированные обоснования *а почему так?*. Я выправила текст - в меру испорченности - секунд за 10–15... Сама выберу, что мне подходит из предлагаемого.

Comment: Вам надо что-то другое выбрать. Ресторан может порадовать борщом или котлетой, но не "возможностью". Да а "возможность буфета" - это полный аут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заведение до сих пор обожают **местные жители,** а может, посещают по старой памяти... Так появляется, во-первых, редкая возможность в несезон **наблюдать ()**  сцены из жизни самых настоящих итальянцев, **обычно передвигающихся** гигантскими семьями: от старушенций в креслах-каталках до новорождённых. Во-вторых, в обеденное время ресторан радует  **разнообразием** открытого буфета – 30 евро с человека (без напитков).

Пояснения:

**вблизи** – перебор наречий в предложении, осложняется чтение;

**сами местные** – звучит не очень корректно, **которые** – книжный стиль;

слово ***возможности*** повторяется два раза.

Comment: Jasmin, Вы как будто не видели мой ответ и никак не агрументируете свой. Я имею в виду двоеточие и "возможность буфета"

Comment: Честно говоря, я решила ответить на вопрос только после того, , как прочитала призыв  Галины: "shampar, найдите огрехи в тексте после моей редактуры" и  исправила текст на свой вкус (как будто видя его впервые, не читая анализа). Теперь о двоеточии. Двоеточие и тире свободно заменяют друг друга почти всегда. Я оставила двоеточие для "красоты", потому что в следующем предложении уже есть тире. А "буфет" мне даже понравился - это же художественный прием - перенос значений.

Comment: Только сейчас понял, что означает "открытый буфет". Это обслуживание по принципу "едите что хотите". Если такой термин приемлем (подтвердите это, пожалуйста), то и со всей конструкцией можно смириться.

Comment: Ок! Автору в Рим! Пусть там голову ломает.

Comment: Jasmin! Спасибо! Всё учтём! Но - нет предела совершенству... Это последняя читка перед публикацией: будем что-то править для чистоты стиля, при правке появятся новые ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Насчет "несезона" мы, кажется, уже дискутировали когда-то. Смысл понятно, но это сленг, по-моему.

На словах "наблюдать вблизи сцены" (какой сцены?) каждый раз сбиваюсь, проходится перечитывать. Как вариант: наблюдать в непосредственной близости  сцены ....

Двоеточие я бы заменил на запятую или тире. Там пояснение, а не перечисление.

"Возможность буфета" (?!). Что-то тут не то. Может у слова *буфет* есть неизвестные мне значения? Скорее всего, речь идет о возможности пользоваться буфетом.

И еще: после *передвигаются* душа просит подробностей (например, передвигаются по побережью, по улицам и т. п.; обычно передвигаются гигантскими семьями)

Comment: "Несезон" согласован - это последняя читка перед публикацией. "Близость сцены* и *Возможность буфета* - предъявлю, кому след.

Comment: Подумала про "сцену". А пару-тройку слов переставить?  *...в несезон вблизи наблюдать сцены из жизни самых настоящих итальянцев...* Это и есть щадящая редактура: если можно не править - нужно не править.

Answer (score 0):

...передвигаются гигантскими семьями (двоеточие). Ведь Вы перечисляете дальше. По поводу "во-первых" - вместо тире запятые вставьте.

Comment: Отвечать на 5 вопросов двумя фразами? Смело.

Comment: shampar, найдите огрехи в тексте после моей редактуры!

Answer (score 0):

Последнюю фразу надо однозначно переделывать. *"Ресторан радует возможностью буфета"* - тут что-то с логикой не то.  Ресторан может порадовать борщом или котлетой, но не "возможностью". Да и само по себе "возможность буфета" - это полный аут по вашему контексту.

И еще. Совершенно непонятно зачем здесь "во-первых" и "во-вторых". Они без контекста совершенно не встают в логический ряд. Ну вот разве так.

[cтоит посетить ресторанчик такой-то].

> **Во-первых**, заведение до сих пор обожают сами местные, а может, посещают по старой памяти... Так появляется редкая возможность в
>   несезон наблюдать вблизи сцены из жизни самых настоящих итальянцев,
>   которые передвигаются гигантскими семьями: от старушенций в
>   креслах-каталках до новорождённых. **Во-вторых, радуют возможности
>   разнообразного открытого буфета: обед 30 евро с человека (без
>   напитков).**

Я не уверен, что выдержал авторский смысл, но то, что было даже после правки, никуда не годится.